# How do I insert br tags in a string using a regular expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string:

```
str = "abc xyz<img src="abc"/> 123 <img src="abc"/><img src="xyz"/>"
```

I want put a `<br/>` before the consecutive image tags at the end of the string so the resulting string will be:

```
str = "abc xyz<img src="abc"/> 123 <br/><img src="abc"/><img src="xyz"/>"
```

Only the consecutive image tags at the end of the string will be preceded by a br.
How would I do this using a regular expression and the `gsub` method?

Comment: Does the (brtag) always precede a (imgtag)

Comment: ths is whaat I want to achieve

Comment: Are `imgtag` and `brtag` the actual text you want to locate and insert or are they your own special code for `<img...>` and `<br>` tags? If the later, then write the real text you want to find and insert in your question, because, as is, it's very misleading and would result in nonsensical answers.

Comment: And if the latter, are they always well-formed image tags?

Comment: imgtag reprsents <img.../> and brtag represents <br>

Comment: Also, are the parenthesis significant? In other words, are the tags enclosed in parenthesis really, or is this another special markup you're using for the question?

Comment: jst edited my question

Comment: @theTinMan I used nokogiri, but while I add `<br/>, it is showing `<br>`. Could you review please?

Comment: @RubyLovely Whereas I can't go through the documentation at the moment, I'd imagine it is because you are using an HTML parser. `<br>` is HTML whereas `<br />` is XHTML. Just a guess, though. I don't have the documentation to prove that this is indeed what Nokogiri is doing.

Comment: @theTinMan Could you help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > str = "abc xyz 123 <img src='smiley.gif' height='42' width='42'>"
 => "abc xyz 123 <img src='smiley.gif' height='42' width='42'>" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > str.gsub(/<img/, "<br/><img")
 => "abc xyz 123 <br/><img src='smiley.gif' height='42' width='42'>"
```

Though a better solution might be to add a class to the image tags that uses CSS to push it to the next line. Possible you just need a "display:block" style

Comment: Hi.. Your solution will precede br for all the image tags.. I only want at the end.

Comment: Thats not what you said in your question. You said "I want put a <br/> before **all the image tags** so the resulting string will be:..." Please be more specific in your question at the start

Comment: I cannot see any easy way to deal with that just via a regex and gsub. How is this text formed? Do you need a BR tag, can you use a CSS style instead?

Comment: Sorry.. I did not get you .. can you please be more specific ?

Comment: str.gsub(/(.+)(<img src='.+' \/>)+/,'\1<br/>\2')
I tried this.. but ths is not working for me.. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(<<-eohtml)
"abc xyz<img src="abc"/> 123 <img src="abc"/><img src="xyz"/>"
eohtml

doc.css("img").each{|i| i.previous = '<br/>'}
puts doc.to_html
```

*Output:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>"abc xyz<br><img src="abc"> 123 <br><img src="abc"><br><img src="xyz">"
</p></body></html>
```

As per the latest edit of OP:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(<<-eohtml)
"abc xyz<img src="abc"/> 123 <img src="abc"/><img src="xyz"/>"
eohtml
doc.css("img[src = abc]")[1].previous = "<br/>"
puts doc.to_html
```

*Output:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>"abc xyz<img src="abc"> 123 <br><img src="abc"><img src="xyz">"
</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Your answer puts a `<br>` between consecutive image tags which, according to the updated question, is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell probably you got the requirement properly. Could you help me to know what he wanted to get from us? As his output and sentence contradicting.